# Haskell - maintaining different states of global variable

Tags: haskell, io, state

I have done some research on stackoverflow to find viable solution to the common problem of maintaining different states of global variable.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467925/maintaining-complex-state-in-haskell) elaborate question that addresses similar concern. It raises important issue of godlike global variable and that's an antipattern in Haskell. I perfectly understand that my situation is similar and I am trying to introduce this antipattern, but I don't really like the answer. It seems that `Netwire` is an overkill for my task at hand, it could be done in much more simple and elegant way.

And I also found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19502268/updating-record-when-referenced-by-multiple-data-structures), but both question and answers address more general concerns and approaches, while I have concrete problem and, hopefully, concrete solution. What I also want (and could not find in previous questions) is to make a qualitative step in understanding of maintaining variable states through the simple example.

In the code below I am trying to update state of the godlike variable from two different places executing `:load` and `:new` commands, but, obviously, it doesn't work.

My question is how to modify following code in order to accommodate possibility of changing global variable value in a functional way? Should I throw away all the code because it represents imperative-style approach and replace it totally new `parseInput` that follows rules of functional world? Should I replace global variable with something else? I assume I could use `IORef` somehow, it seems appropriate. Or `ST Monad` as [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880555/st-monad-code-smell) recommends.

What would be the easiest and straightforward step to address this problem without an overkill? I understand that I might need to better grasp the notion of Monads (State Monad in particular) and I am ready to learn how they could help with addressing this particular problem. But the articles I have read so far ([this](https://wiki.haskell.org/State_Monad) and [this](http://brandon.si/code/the-state-monad-a-tutorial-for-the-confused/)), didn't help much. I assume that State Monad is not really appropriate because my example does not have return value, only updated state. If I am wrong, could you please explain how and what missing links would help me to understand states in Haskell better?

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}

import Text.Regex.PCRE
import System.Console.Haskeline
import TH (litFile)
import System.FilePath
import System.IO
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Data.List 

mydata :: [Int]
mydata = [0]

saveDataToFile :: [Int] -> IO ()
saveDataToFile mydata = withFile "data.txt" WriteMode $ \h -> System.IO.hPutStr h (unwords $ map show mydata)

loadDataFromFile :: [Int]
loadDataFromFile = map read . words $ [litFile|data.txt|]

help :: InputT IO ()
help = liftIO $ mapM_ putStrLn
       [ ""
       , ":help     - this help"
       , ":q        - quit"
       , ":commands - list available commands"
       , ""
       ]

commands :: InputT IO ()
commands = liftIO $ mapM_ putStrLn
       [ ""
       , ":show     - display data"
       , ":save     - save results to file"
       , ":load     - loads data from file"
       , ":new      - generate new element "
       , ""
       ]

parseInput :: String -> InputT IO ()
parseInput inp
  | inp =~ "^\\:q"        = return ()

  | inp =~ "^\\:he"       = help >> mainLoop

  | inp =~ "^\\:commands" = commands >> mainLoop

  | inp =~ "^\\:show" = do
    liftIO $ putStrLn $ unwords $ map show mydata
    mainLoop 

  | inp =~ "^\\:save" = do
    liftIO $ saveDataToFile mydata
    mainLoop

  | inp =~ "^\\:load" = do
    let mydata = loadDataFromFile -- <-- should update mydata 
    mainLoop

  | inp =~ "^\\:new" = do
    let mydata = mydata ++ [last mydata + 1] -- <-- should update mydata
    mainLoop

  | inp =~ ":" = do
    outputStrLn $ "\nNo command \"" ++ inp ++ "\"\n"
    mainLoop

  | otherwise = handleInput inp

handleInput :: String -> InputT IO ()
handleInput inp = mainLoop

mainLoop :: InputT IO ()
mainLoop = do
  inp <- getInputLine "% "
  maybe (return ()) (parseInput) inp

greet :: IO ()
greet = mapM_ putStrLn
        [ ""
        , "          MyProgram"
        , "=============================="
        , "For help type \":help\""
        , ""
        ]

main :: IO ()
main = do 
    greet 
    runInputT defaultSettings (mainLoop)
```

PS. I use Template Haskell definitions (TH module) from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12716215/load-pure-global-variable-from-file/12717160#12717160).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One clean way to handle this is to add [`StateT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.4.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Strict.html#t:StateT) to your transformer stack.

Instead of using the type `InputT IO` you'd use either `StateT [Int] (InputT IO)` or `InputT (StateT [Int] IO)`. Since `InputT` has more operations to mess around with lifting, I'd use `InputT (StateT [Int] IO)` to keep the complicated operations on the outside.

To make things simple I'd add an orphan [`MonadState`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-State-Class.html) instance for `MonadState m => MonadState (InputT m)`

```
instance MonadState s m => MonadState s (InputT m) where
    get = lift get
    put = lift . put
    state = lift . state
```

Then when you want to modify the state you'd use `get`, `put`, or `state`.

```
  | inp =~ "^\\:new" = do
    mydata <- get                     -- reads the state
    put $ mydata ++ [last mydata + 1] -- updates the state
    mainLoop
```

You can then clean up the type signatures to make your code more general. Instead of only working on `InputT (StateT [Int] IO)` you can make the code work for `(MonadState [Int] m, MonadIO m) => InputT m`.

To run a `StateT` use [`runStateT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.4.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#v:runStateT). If you change the type of `mainloop` to `InputT (StateT [Int] IO) ()` or the more general `(MonadState [Int] m, MonadIO m) => InputT m ()` then you can run it with

```
main :: IO ()
main = do 
    greet 
    runStateT (runInputT defaultSettings mainLoop) []
--  ^          ^ run the outer InputT              ^
--  run the inner StateT ..... with starting state []
```

Comment: Where did you import `lift` function from? And should it be `get = lift . get` instead of `get = lift get`? Also I am changing signature of `parseInput` function from `String -> InputT IO ()` to (as you suggested) `String -> InputT (StateT [Int] IO)`, but getting error `Couldn't match type ‘StateT [Int] IO’ with ‘IO’
    Expected type: String -> InputT IO ()
      Actual type: String -> InputT (StateT [Int] IO) ()` in the `mainLoop` function. How could I rewrite `mainLoop` to accommodate changes of `parseInput` type?

Comment: `lift` is from the [`MonadTrans`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.4.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Class.html) class. `lift get` is right; `get` isn't a function.